# Recursion in scala wont stop

Tags: scala, recursion, knights-tour, immutable-collections

I have a method which helps me to solve a knight's tour. I want my recursion to stop as soon as I have found a solution however It keeps going on and on.

At the end it returns nearly 20 different solutions. I have added my code below, Can Someone please point out what is wrong here?

```
def myRecursion(dimension: Int, solution: Solution) : Option[Solution] = {

    if ( dimension * dimension == solution.size) {
        println("Stop it now")
        Some(solution)
    } else {
        val movesAvailable = possibleMoves(dimension, solution, solution.head) 
        val bestm = bestMoves(movesAvailable)

        if ( bestm.isDefined ) {
            myRecursion(dimension, bestm.get ::: solution)
        } else {
            movesAvailable.foreach{ x => 
                if(myRecursion(dimension, x:: solution).isDefined){
                    x::solution;
                } 
            }
            None

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Unfortunately That did not solve my problem. It stops as soon as the  solution.size is 1. But im trying to stop it when solution includes (dimension * dimension ) number of elements

Comment: My mistake on analysis, dimension is never increase but the solution size is. so its the other way round. change dimension * dimension == solution.size to dimension * dimension <= solution.size

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Unfortunately that still shows the same output as "=="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
movesAvailable.foreach{ x => 
                if(myRecursion(dimension, x:: solution).isDefined){
                    x::solution;
                } 
            }
None
```

Thats probably your issue. You're calling your function recursively in a loop, but you don't actually exit the loop if its successful. You could probably switch that around to a takeWhile that keeps going while myRecursions returns None.

Also, that chunk of code isn't doing anything right now - You've got an if statement that evaluates to something, but then you return None no matter what.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I thought I would exit the loop when I return  x::solution. What solution would you recommend if you had to rewrite this code? I will definitely look into takeWhile but I dont know how to fix the if statement

Comment: I can't tell from the code, but presumably movesAvailable is a List of some type? foreach is not the function you want to use there, as what that does is "Loop through each item in your list, run some function, then throw away the result". Its used for things with side effects, for example - printing to the console everything in the list.

Comment: In this situation, takeWhile is preferable. What this function does is "Look at an item in a list, evaluate a function that returns a boolean, and if the result is true, continue taking more items, otherwise stop". So your code would look like

movesAvailable.takeWhile(x => myRecursion(dimension, x:: solution).isEmpty).headOption

The headOption means "Take the first item in the list" if it exists.

Comment: your answer makes total sense and I completely understand now but when implementing what you have suggested I receive an error about type mismatch , " found   : List[Product with Serializable]"

Comment: "Product with Serializable" typically means that there are multiple types being mixed together. What is the type of movesAvailable? List[Solution]? Try putting in intermediate variables with type annotations to chase down where the problem is.

Comment: The type of movesAvailable is a single coordinate , so every time a coordinate leads to finding a solution I will add it to the Solution

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you very much. However now I dont get the solution , I just get 24 coordinates whereas it should be 25

Comment: Sorry, you may actually want dropWhile rather than takeWhile (dropWhile - drop the elements that match this criteria, takeWhile - take the elements that match this criteria).